# Where could I find some code examples about Integration Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration, functional-programming

I have methods that interact with DB and external files. I need to write integration tests, however I am not sure how to.

Do you know where I can find some source codes about integration testing with Database or External File?

If you write a test method that tests a production method in which there are calls to other methods, is this an integration test, system test or functional test? It's not unit test obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Integration Tests are test of all part of application usually from user/external system point of view.

For DB app with GUI it can be Sikuli (http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/helloworld/helloworld-win.html)

For DB app without GUI use any scripting language with test framework (f.exmpl.Python: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html)

Here is example of testing external resources like DB: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2009/07/python-mock-testing-techniques-and.html